# Правильно связать сервлет и jQuery. Отправить post-запрос, редиректнуть на страницу и принять файл.

Tags: jquery, servlet, java

Есть сервлет, который принимает запрос, парсит содержимое и по результатам отправляет файл.

```
        digester.parse(request.getInputStream());
        int hashCode = snaRequest.hashCode();

        String fileName = ResponseXMLData.getValue(hashCode);
        File file = new File(realPath + "\\" + fileName);
        ServletContext context  = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        String mimetype = context.getMimeType(realPath);
        if (mimetype == null) {
            mimetype = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        response.setContentType(mimetype);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, response.getOutputStream());
```

Есть jQuery-скрипт, который отправляет этот запрос из соответствующей формы.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button").click(function()   {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post("test",
                    $("textarea").val());
            window.location.href = "test";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Если убрать `window.location.href = "test";`, то текст отправляется в сервлет, но не происходит аплоада файла, с редиректом ругается на то, что текст передан не валидный.
Как грамотно передать запрос и получить файл?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вам нужно не просто получить данные с сервера, но и предложить пользователю сохранить их в файл на жёстком диске. Напрямую через AJAX это сделать нельзя, из-за ограничений безопасности JavaScript'у не разрешается взаимодействовать с файловой системой пользователя (даже отображать диалог сохранения файла). Но есть костыль: можно создать `iframe` и установить его `src` в нужный вам адрес. Тогда пользователю будет предложено сохранить переданный с сервера файл. Если обязательно нужно отправлять POST-запрос, то можно ручками собрать внутри `iframe`'а форму с нужными вам полями и отправить её. Реалзовывать всё вышеописанное самостоятельно необязательно, всё это уже реализовано в плагине [jQuery File Download Plugin for Ajax](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/).

Comment: Это вариант, спасибо. Но разве нельзя совместить редирект на страницу с post-запросом? В моем случае, изначальная проблема, которая возникла - я не мог валидно отправить xml-документ через textarea, так как к тексту приписывается название пост-параметра. А в jQuery я не могу одновременно с post-запросом редиректнуть на страницу. За аплоад файла отвечает сервлет, то есть в теории, вызывать непосредственно загрузку файла из jQuery-скрипта мне не обязательно.